# copy file from source to destination in UBI file system

Tags: c, file

I want to copy file from source to destination. But in case of destination folder size is small compare to source file. It does not fail write, always return success and this behaviour I have observed in UBI file system only.

```
while ((size = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZ, source)) > 0)
{
    size_t size_2 = fwrite(buffer, 1, size, destination);
    if (size_2 != size)
    {
        retval = -1;
        break;
    }
}
```

In UBIFS supports write-back, In which file changes are cached and go to the flash later. Any one know how to verify write status for this.

Comment: So what is the problem if the write doesn't fail? Be aware that UBIFS has compression so the write can succeed even if it appears that the target directory does not have enough space.

Comment: if target dir not have enough space then I want to return -1. It show write action false so I will take necessary action on that

Comment: But it didn't fail. That's why it didn't return an error. It seems you are expecting it to fail when it isn't going to. It is not obvious from command line how much more can be written to a ubifs file system so that may be leading you to an incorrect conclusion that the write should fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fsync to verify the write-back status.

To quote from the following source:

> transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data of ... the file
>   referred to by the file descriptor fd to the disk device (or other
>   permanent storage device) so that all changed information can be
>   retrieved even if the system crashes or is rebooted.  This includes
>   writing through or flushing a disk cache if present

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html

Comment: From the manual:
Calling fsync() does not necessarily ensure that the entry in the
       directory containing the file has also reached disk.  For that an
       explicit fsync() on a file descriptor for the directory is also
       needed

Comment: int destFileNo = fileno(destination);
    int statusFlush = fflush(destination);
    printf("fflush status; :: %d\n", statusFlush);
    int statusvalue = fsync(destFileNo);
    printf(stderr,"\n statusvalue :: %d\n", statusvalue); I have sed this one

Comment: @gauri in that case the write happened as expected. Why do you think the sync is failing ?